# Move File in ExpressJS/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file, ubuntu, file-upload, express

I'm trying to move uploaded file from `/tmp` to `home` directory using NodeJS/ExpressJS:

```
fs.rename('/tmp/xxxxx', '/home/user/xxxxx', function(err){
    if (err) res.json(err);

console.log('done renaming');
});
```

But it didn't work and no error encountered. But when new path is also in `/tmp`, that will work.

Im using Ubuntu, `home` is in different partition. Any fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, fs.rename does not move file between two different disks/partitions. This is the **correct** behaviour. `fs.rename` provides identical functionality to `rename(2)` in linux.

Read the related issue posted [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2703).

To get what you want, you would have to do something like this:

```
var source = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/source');
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/dest');

source.pipe(dest);
source.on('end', function() { /* copied */ });
source.on('error', function(err) { /* error */ });
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to use `fs.writeFile`. `fs.unlink` in callback will remove the temp file from tmp directory.

```
var oldPath = req.files.file.path;
var newPath = ...;

fs.readFile(oldPath , function(err, data) {
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
        fs.unlink(oldPath, function(){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: what is **data** in this? and how can i get it from the request object?

Comment: what will be the new path?

Answer (score 4):

Updated ES6 solution ready to use with promises and async/await:

```
function moveFile(from, to) {
    const source = fs.createReadStream(from);
    const dest = fs.createWriteStream(to);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        source.on('end', resolve);
        source.on('error', reject);
        source.pipe(dest);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example taken from: [Node.js in Action](http://www.manning.com/cantelon/)

> A  move() function that renames, if possible, or falls back to copying

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function move (oldPath, newPath, callback) {
fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
if (err) {
if (err.code === 'EXDEV') {
copy();
} else {
callback(err);
}
return;
}
callback();
});
function copy () {
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(oldPath);
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(newPath);
readStream.on('error', callback);
writeStream.on('error', callback);
readStream.on('close', function () {
fs.unlink(oldPath, callback);
});
readStream.pipe(writeStream);
}
}
```