# File renamed before created

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fs

I've just started to learn Node.js & stuck straight away with the following code:

```
const fs = require(`fs`);

fs.appendFile(`mynewfile1.txt`, `Hello content!`, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`Saved!`);
});

fs.rename(`mynewfile1.txt`, `myrenamedfile.txt`, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`File Renamed!`);
});
```

It's located in `app.js` & **there are no other files in this directory** before run.

When I run it (with `node app.js` bash command), it *stably* outputs:

```
> File Renamed!
> Saved!
```

I understand that both operations run asynchronously & I assume that renaming a file must be faster than creating a new one, but `fs.rename` is supposed to throw if the file we attempt to rename does not exist and well, it does if the first statement is not present. Otherwise it pretends like everything is ok.

I assume that this happens because before executing costly I/O Node somehow evaluates operations and, in my case, instead of creating a new file & re-naming it, just creates file named `myrenamedfile.txt` straight away.

My questions are:

1. I'm I right in my last assumption? If so, could you please point out to some documentation regarding this, otherwise, could you please explain why this happens?
2. Could you also point me to the rules that regulates behaviour of `fs.rename` in this case? I mean since, it clearly doesn't actually re-name an existing file (because it is not created at that moment yet), it should be doing something different. So, where is the documentation for this "something different"? [The main documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) does not specify it.

---

UPD:

Big thanks to all nice folk who had responded until now, I know that either `promisify` from `utils` module or experimental `require('fs').promises` might be used to chain the operations if needed, but the question is about *why* the code works & doesn't throw the error, not *how* the operations might be chained together.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The issue is because of the async functions. You can wrap the appendFile function in a Promise and use safely before renaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your assumption about asynchronous flow is correct. Since the file is not present initially and the **rename** is fired irrespective of if **appendFile** is completed or not, It will throw an error as `no such file or directory`.

The console shows: `File Renamed!`, because you just printed it without any condition.

To handle this scenario, either use respective **sync methods** like:

```
const fs = require(`fs`);

fs.appendFileSync(`mynewfile1.txt`, `Hello content!`);
console.log(`Saved!`);

fs.renameSync(`mynewfile1.txt`, `myrenamedfile.txt`);
console.log(`File Renamed!`);
```

Or use **async/await**:

```
const fs = require(`fs`);
const util = require('util');

const appendAndRename = async () => {
    try {
        await util.promisify(fs.appendFile)(`mynewfile1.txt`, `Hello content!`);
        console.log(`Saved!`);

        await util.promisify(fs.rename)(`mynewfile1.txt`, `myrenamedfile.txt`);
        console.log(`File Renamed!`);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
}

appendAndRename();
```

Make sure your **await** statements are always wrapped in **try/catch** block and the immediate parent function is declared with **async** keyword.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have a question regarding the "...because you just printed it without any condition" part. In both pieces of code, I put `if (err) throw err;` which is supposed to throw any error to global scope & hence "kill" the script if any error is passed to the callback. So, do you have any idea why then the `File Renamed!` is still being printed? :)

Comment: Yes you are right .. It will kill the process and exit the execution. I tried to reproduce your scenario, but for me its working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In case the "File Renamed!" is executed first, the "Saved!" part will create a new file called `mynewfile1.txt`

If you want order to be preserved, use in an async function:

```
const fs = require(`fs`);

await fs.appendFile(`mynewfile1.txt`, `Hello content!`);
console.log(`Saved!`);

await fs.rename(`mynewfile1.txt`, `myrenamedfile.txt`);
console.log(`File Renamed!`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the working (tested) code snippet below. Used built-in 'util' module to promisify the fs functions.

```
    const fs = require(`fs`);
    const util = require('util');

    async function doTheOpAsync() {
        const appendFile = util.promisify(fs.appendFile);
        const rename = util.promisify(fs.rename);
        try{
            await appendFile(`mynewfile1.txt`, `Hello content!`);
            console.log(`Saved!`);
            await rename(`mynewfile1.txt`, `myrenamedfile.txt`);
            console.log(`File Renamed!`);
        }catch(ex){
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }
    doTheOpAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've finally found some time to do research on this topic & my findings seem to explain what's happening pretty well. Here are the most possible answers:

1. Nope.

Node neither pre-compile the code nor "batches updates/operations" (in the fashion that, for instance, React does).

[fs.rename](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/bd8a7196fc15ab7ae4976c3fb728267ab6864a67/lib/fs.js#L746), is executed exactly when the compiler reaches the place where it's called & no black magic happens until here.

2. Sure, but the answer is hidden *very deep*.

[Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) references [a Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) hinting that `fs.rename` ([at least on Unix-based operational systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571921/9430588) which I use) will behave exactly the same as Linux `rename` does.

So, we've got into OS-level commands.

Now, operations on Unix-based OSs are mostly [atomic operations](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/%7Eivana/courses/ps/sistemi_knjige/pomocno/apue/APUE/0201433079/ch03lev1sec11.html) which (on a very basic level) means that operations are performed in such a way that it's impossible to distinguish any piece of it. So, an operation cannot be divided into smaller pieces.

For our particular case, it's important to know that this concept implies that when an operation is performed, only the operation itself may perceive any progress on the task it's doing. the rest of the system will start to see the result of operation only when the operation is 100% finished. It's impossible to perceive the state when 99% of the work is done from outside of the operation. Otherwise, the operation wouldn't be atomic.

Now, there are several references ([a comment on PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php#2430), [an answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/347376), [an answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/255811)) which say that any writing/reading operation started before rename operation will peacefully continue in the atomic operations world.

Considering that `fs.appendFile` is just a wrapper for the combination of `fs.open` & `fs.write`, we can say that, `fs.appendFile` is **not** atomic.

So, most likely, this is what's happening when you run the mentioned script on a Unix-based system:

1. `fs.appendFile` is reached. [It's code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/bd8a7196fc15ab7ae4976c3fb728267ab6864a67/lib/fs.js#L1431) is executed.
2. `fs.appendFile` itself is synchronous, so, it is fully executed until the call to `fs.writeFile`.
3. In our case, the first async operation is the call to `fs.open`. So, `fs.writeFile` is executed all the way down till the call to `fs.open`, then async operation is added to the queue. JS compiler can now return back to the file it was initially executing (our source file).
4. It sees `fs.rename` & starts execution.
5. Meanwhile `fs.open` is already resolved since creation of an empty file is super fast. However, `appendFile` hasn't finished running yet since writing operation haven't even started. The compiler adds the call to `writeAll` to async queue.
6. So, now, `fs.rename` is being executed while we already have the file but it's empty just yet. However, it doesn't matter since what is needed is file existence, so, rename succeeds & `File Renamed!` is printed to the console.
7. Write operation is not anyhow affected by rename since it identifies file with its internal id rather than with the name, so, it successfully finishes writing & `Saved!` is printed to the console.

Unfortunately, I can't confirm my guess with a test since it's obviously impossible to execute anything meaningful (like reading file content to confirm it's empty at this moment) in `fs.rename` callback since OS operations are much quicker than JS code. Also, it's impossible to pause/postpone/block them.

If any [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) guru will ever read this, please let me know if my idea seems to be about right.

---

Finally, I found a way to test my guess:

If I write a really huge amount of data (like `'Hello content!'.repeat(9e6)`), I have enough time to call `fs.statSync` in `fs.rename` callback before the write operation is done. It reports that file exists and its size is 0.

If I then call the same in `appendFile` callback, it reports all the same except file's `size` is now `126000000`.

Also, and most importantly, if I add this line:

```js
console.log(execSync('lsof myrenamedfile.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}));
```

in `rename` callback, I can see node process that is still writing to file, which looks something like this:

```sh
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE     SIZE/OFF           NODE NAME
node    50837  username   20w   REG    1,4   0 15997608   myrenamedfile.txt
```