# ENOENT Error - I'm successfully uploading files but can't move them

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I'm successfully uploading files to the temp directory, and want to move them to the directory `profile_pictures`. It seems like such a *simple* thing, yet I have been stuck here for an hour!

[image]

Pretty simple code to do this with *Express* and *fs*:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("User uploading profile picture...");

    var tmp_path = req.files.profile_picture.path; // get the temporary location of the file
    var ext = path.extname(req.files.profile_picture.name); // get the extension of the file with the path module

    var target_path = '/profile_pictures/' + req.body.username + ext; // set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory

    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function (err) { // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
        if (err) throw err;

        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function (err) { // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.profile_picture.size + ' bytes');
        });
    });
});
```

But this results in the error:

> Error: ENOENT, rename 'tmp/5162-2fftn.jpg'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'tmp/5162-2fftn.jpg'

The image at top is a screen shot of my SFTP manager connected to the working directory of this app, so clearly the directory does exist!

**What's my mistake??**

Comment: You are continuing despite errors, if there is `err` you shouldn't continue. Also your second callback doesn't declare `err` parameter so you are not knowing what the error is from unlink.

Comment: @Esailija oh I see. Well the error is at `fs.rename`. I'll repair the error handling

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path? The relative path might think the root is something else than you expect

Comment: I haven't tried that, no. I'm using a linux server; What does the root part of a linux path look like..? Like in Windows it's `C:\ `

Comment: nothing to do with OS, I mean when you pass a relative path like `./tmp` to `fs.rename` it will figure out the absolute path on its own which might not be the correct one. Try absolute path like `"/var/www/node/tmp/file.jpg"` or such.

Comment: Also your target path for rename starts with a `/profile_pictures` .. that can't be right

Comment: @Esailija why? Should it be `./profile_pictures`?

Comment: /profile_pictures would mean root level folder like var or etc

Answer (score 0):

I spent a good couple hours myself tying to address this issue.  Take a look here for clarification,
https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2703

Here the thread that actually pointed me in the right direction,
[Move File in ExpressJS/NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649550/move-file-in-expressjs-nodejs)

Yes, fs.rename does not move file between two different disks/partitions. This is the correct behaviour. fs.rename provides identical functionality to rename(2) in linux.